# Any idea why I keep losing permissions on my Documents folder?

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, permission, zsh

For some reason, I keep losing all access to `~/Documents` folder via shell.

For example:

```
me@MyMac ~ % ls -l ~/Documents                       
total 0
ls: /Users/me/Documents: Operation not permitted
me@MyMac ~ % sudo chmod -R +rw ~/Documents          
chmod: /Users/me/Documents: Operation not permitted
```

I can still access documents normally through Finder and other applications so the issue seems to be specific to shell scripts/interactive sessions. Any thoughts on what could be causing this or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to grant Full Disk Access to Terminal in System Prefs > Security & Privacy.